# GWT server<->client message bus?

Tags: java, gwt, event-handling, websocket, asyncsocket

Errai provides one, for example. Are there any other solutions providing event bus implementations that allow the client to receive *realtime* events from the server and share client events with the server?

Comment: Well, when you need realtime (whatever your definition of realtime is), I would say it depends on whether it supports WebSockets or not. Any other technology needs to pull the server, Errai needs to do that to, in an environment where no WebSockets are available. Correct me if I am wrong, please. For WebSockets communication, have a look at [Atmosphere](https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere). But that is no bus.

Answer (score 0):

Found a gwt lib that could match what I have been looking for:

http://code.google.com/p/gwt-comet/

Example:

[Basic use of gwt-comet for GWT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6006162/basic-use-of-gwt-comet-for-gwt)

But gwt-comet seems to be unmaintained since May 2011. Lots of open bug reports and no changes in the repository. No maven integration.

Similar discussion:

[How can I connect GWT to CometD/Bayeux events?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1899925/how-can-i-connect-gwt-to-cometd-bayeux-events)

Alternative using the existing cometd implementation at github.com:

http://code.google.com/p/cometd4gwt/

It has no maven ingration and the discussion group contains 4 threads only.

Seems like http://code.google.com/p/gwteventservice/ is the only proper solution right now because it has maven support, most issues have been solved and the last svn commit was in dec 2012.

JIRA request for cometd GWT integration: http://bugs.cometd.org/browse/COMETD-63